Direct input elements in shinydashboard sidebar
I was wondering if I could modify the following shiny app and put the sliderInput into the sidebar section :
 library(shinydashboard)
    
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "DB manager"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
          menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
        )
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # First tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                  fluidRow(
                    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                    
                    box(
                      title = "Controls",
                      sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                    )
                  )
          ),
          
          # Second tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                  h2("Widgets tab content")
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      set.seed(122)
      histdata <- rnorm(500)
      
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
        hist(data)
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)

Something like :
Below I have used the menuItem inside menuItem. for the first sleider, I can see the plot but for the second I can not !
library(shinydashboard)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "DB manager"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        # sidebarMenu(
        #   menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
        #            sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)),
        #   menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
        # )
        
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                   sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
                   menuItem("", tabName = "dashboard2")
          ),
          menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"),
                   sliderInput("slider1", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
                   menuItem("", tabName = "dashboard3"))
        )
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # First tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "dashboard2",
                  fluidRow(
                    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))
                    
                  )
          ),
          
          # Second tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "dashboard3",
                  fluidRow(
                    box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250))
                    
                  )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      set.seed(122)
      histdata <- rnorm(500)
      
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
        hist(data)
      })
      
      output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
        data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider1)]
        hist(data)
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)

Any Idea how I could achieve that ?

When you have a child item, you need to define another menuItem or menuSubItem.  Try the code below.  Please note that (in the code below) you cannot access tabName dashboard, but only dashboard2.
sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
               sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
               menuItem("Dashboard2", tabName = "dashboard2", icon = icon("dashboard"))
               ),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )

Update:  Try this it works fine for me.  Please note that you have to select the tab "A" or "B" to view the plot.  The main menuItem only lets you see the selections possible in the sidebar - like slider or other items. You can also define ID for the sidebarmenu, and then update the tabs automatically, whenever there is a change in input via slider by using observers. Define expandedName, and access it via input$sidebarItemExpanded to update the tabs automatically via observer.
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DB manager"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"), expandedName = "tab1",
               sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
               menuItem("A", tabName = "dashboard2")
      ),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"), expandedName = "tab2",
               sliderInput("slider1", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
               menuItem("B", tabName = "dashboard3"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard2",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))
              )
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard3",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250))
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, { 
    print(input$sidebarItemExpanded)
    if ( input$sidebarItemExpanded == "tab1") updateTabItems(session,"tabs","dashboard2")
    
    if (input$sidebarItemExpanded=="tab2")   updateTabItems(session,"tabs","dashboard3") 
    
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    # data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider1)]
    # hist(data)
    plot(cars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


your trick works just for the first menuItem, if I try to put the same slider into the second menuItem, I have to always manually click on the fake menu
menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"),                sliderInput("slider1", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),                menuItem("fake", tabName = "dashboard3"))     )
it will not switch automatically !

I am not sure of the problem you are describing.  Perhaps you could update your code in the question to describe the problem - either here or as a new question.  Please look here for details on menuItems.

I have updated the code using your proposed method !

nope ! and that is exactly the problem, I'm looking for something like observe or observe event that does it automatically !! Like if I am on Dashboard menu in sidebar, it activate the dashboard2 tab in main dashboardbody without me manually click on "A" !!!
And after all, I'm looking for a pretty way for a foldable solution in my sidebar, to click on menu, expand the sidebar, provide the input and see the result in main dashboard body, then select next menu, provide the input again inside the sidebar, and see the result in the main dashboard body ...

we almost there !
The app works if we change the slider every time we switch the menu !
Can't we say if we are in the menuItem dashboard show us the dashboard2 and if we are in widgets then show the dashboard3 ?! without changing the slider values ?!
Because imagine you have a file input instead of slider !

Please try the updated code.

wow ! expandedName !! never sow that before !
That is it ! thank you !
